# BufferedReader is closed when returned from method

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm writing code to read a file and process it and I'm splitting logic into many small methods. So I have a method to read the file and return BufferedReader and another one to do logic with the returned BufferedReader object. But when I try to read lines from the BufferedReader object in the second method it gives me [java.io.IOException: Stream Closed].

The method I used to read the file and return BufferedReader

```
private static BufferedReader readFile(String file) {
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
        System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine()); // this line is working successfully
        return bufferedReader;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any idea why the happens and how to solve it ?

Comment: `try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file))` - what do you think is happening here?

Comment: Can you post the exception stack also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using try-with-resources:

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
```

This line is creating a `FileInputStream` which can be used inside your `try` block. As soon as you leave your `try` block, the `close()` method will be called onto the stream. So if you return the stream or its `BufferedReader`, the stream will already be closed. You should not use try-with-resources or even better, return whatever you need from the stream instead of the stream itself.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the problem here lies in the use of try-with-resources, and AutoCloseable interface. However, i would like to point out that the way you read the file is the "old fashioned" way. We now have the Files, Paths, and Stream classes to facilitate reading of files. this uses java NIO, returns a Stream and is better overall:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(pathToFile))
```

additionally, nothing has to be closed here